# Set password on virtual directory in IIS Express with AppCmd

Tags: iis, iis-express, appcmd

I have a vdir with a physicalPath that points to a file share. Setting the "userName" and "password" attributes to a user with access to that share in the vdir config section in applicationhost.config works fine, but the password is then in clear text.

I want this password encrypted in the applicationhost.config file.

The only option I've found is to use "appcmd.exe" to do this, but I am unable to get it to work in the obvious way:

```
appcmd.exe set vdir /vdir.name:"Default Web Site/img" /password:"ThePassword"
```

I get this error:

ERROR ( hresult:80090016, message:Failed to commit configuration changes.
Keyset does not exist )

I have tried with an elevated cmd prompt, does nothing. Setting the other attributes, like userName, works fine.

Comment: Usually that means the machine key is corrupt so that encryption failed. You will have to get that fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

`appcmd.exe set vdir "Default Web Site/img" /username:user /password:password`